# How to get the sum of all integers between m and n in a loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I am having problems acquiring the sum of all integers between `m` and `n`. In the code, I must input two integers `m` and `n`, and calculate and display the sum of all the integers from `m` to `n`.

The sum should be calculated using a loop to repeatedly add numbers to a total and I cannot use a formula to calculate the result. The code I produced so far is displayed below:

```
m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a second number: "))
sum = 0

for i in range (m,n):
    m+n
    sum += i
    print(i)
```

Comment: So what is the issue in the above code?

Comment: When i enter numbers 4 and 5, the result is just 4 which is incorrect

Comment: @rico99 check my answer

Comment: `range(n, m)` is exclusive for `m`, meanining the loop goes to `m-1` (inclusive). You could have read that in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: I have rolled back your latest edit. You're not supposed to edit the code in your question so it matches the solution. If you've found a good answer, accept it from the tickmark next to the correct answer, don't edit your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `range(m, n+1)` in order to include `n` in the range.

```
for i in range (m,n+1):
    s += i
    print(i)

print(s)
```

For example `range(4,6)` will give you `[4,5]` but `range(4,5)` will give you only `[4]`.

Comment: nothing happens after i enter the first two integers

Comment: @rico99 what you entered?

Comment: ok thanks, it is now returning numbers between m and n but i want to add all numbers between and including m and n together?

Comment: yes, it includes both `m` and `n` like this,  you tried it? print the `sum` after the loop.

Answer (score 7):

A few issues I see in the above code are -

1. You are printing the value of `i` , which are integers from `m` to `n`  (not including `n`) , and you are not printing the `sum` .
2. You are doing `m+n` and just throwing away the result inside the loop, that line does not do anything in the loop and you do not need it.
3. **Main** - You are going till `n-1` , not including `n` since `range(start, stop)` only goes till `stop - 1` , it is exclusive of `stop` . You would need to do `range(m,n+1)` .
4. You should not use `sum` as variable name as it would shadow the built-in function - [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) .

Comment: #4 is important, and all the books and tutorials that I have come across miss this point completely. Just to mention, this is a better answer than the accepted one.

Answer (score 3):

`range(m,n)` iterates from `m` to `n-1`. If you want sum of numbers from m to n (including m and n)

```
for i in range(m, n+1):
    sum+=i
```

Comment: **Don't** use `sum` as a variable name, because it shadows the [built-in `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) function.

Answer (score 2):

Just call the `sum` function on the range, adding `1` to `n` to include n in the sum as ranges are *half open* so the upper bound is not inclusive:

```
m = int(input("Enter a number: "))
n = int(input("Enter a second number: "))


print(sum(range(m, n+1)))
```

Don't use `sum` as a variable name as it shadows the builtin function sum which if you leave sum defined in your code will make it obvious why

Comment: The OP had a restraint to use a for loop to do the sum, although this is a good solution to win the range.

Comment: @holroy, the OP cannot use a formula, there is no restraint on using sum,it is with a loop.

Comment: see his second paragraph, I read that as the OP needs to write the loop him self, not a hidden loop within the definition of `sum`