# Writing code that adds up integers between 2 numbers

Tags: python, sum

This is what I have so far but I'm not even sure it is correct:

```
count = 0
for i in range (4, 833):
     count += 1
```

Here is the exact requirements: write code that will add up all of the integers between 4 and 832 (including 4 and 832) and print this number to the console (use a loop)

Comment: `sum(range(4, 833+1))` if you want to avoid the loop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get sum of all integers between m and n in a loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32036764/how-to-get-sum-of-all-integers-between-m-and-n-in-a-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
count = 0
for i in range (4, 833):
    count += i
```

Just change it to i, so you add 4+5+6...+832

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct.  You are COUNTING all the integers from 4 to 832, not SUMMING them.  It is only a one character fix.